# Plotting $r(t) = (sin(t), t)$

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, vectors, 3d

Sketch the curve with the given vector equation. Indicate with an arrow the direction in which t increases.

$$r(t) = (\sin t, t)$$

I have no idea how to sketch this. The closest example I saw in the book was a cylinder moving upward and the only reason they gave us was that $x^2 +y^2 = 1 = \cos^2 (x) + \sin^2 (x)$. I can't find any examples online. Can someone please explain how to approach this problem and problems like these?

**Edit:** Since there are two elements, do i graph it in 2d? Or do I make $z = 0$? Am I just supposed to plot points and graph it that way?

Comment: Plotting points would be start.  Let me ask this...how would you sketch $(x,\sin x)$?  You have probably done it dozens of times.

Comment: yeah i had trig aaages ago. ok im guessing its supposed to be some kind of sin graph so do I graph it in a normal x y plane and does it make it a sideways sin graph? i don't have a graphing calculator

Comment: i see now it is a sideways sine graph